# PHP Remove all Files From a Directory - Exclude File Extension

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, glob

I am trying for the life of me to find the best way to delete all files in a single directory excluding a single file extension, ie anything that is not `.zip`

The current method I have used so far which successfully deletes all files is:

```
$files = glob('./output/*');
foreach($files as $file)
{ 
    if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

I have tried modifying this like so:

```
$files = glob('./output/**.{!zip}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file)
{
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

However, I am not hitting the desired result. I have changed the line as follows which has deleted only the zip file itself (so I can do the opposite of desired).

```
$files = glob('./output/*.{zip}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

I understand that there are other methods to read directory contents and use `strpos`/`preg_match` etc to delete accordingly. I have also seen many other methods, but these seem to be quite long winded or intended for recursive directory loops.

I am certainly not married to `glob()`, I would simply like to know the simplest/most efficient way to delete all files in a single directory that are not a `.zip` file.

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(I just use `array_diff()` to get all files which are different to `*.zip` and then i go through these files and unlink them)

```
<?php

    $files = array_diff(glob("*.*"), glob("*.zip"));
    foreach($files as $file) {
      if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$exclude = array("zip");
$files = glob("output/*");
foreach($files as $file) {
    $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array($extension, $exclude)) unlink($file);
}
```

This code works by having an array of excluded extensions, it loads up all files in a directory then checks for the extension of each file. If the extension is in the exclusion list then it doesn't get deleted. Else, it does.

Comment: I will have to store this for later use. Many thanks for the input and I understand/appreciate the use of `PATHINFO_EXTENSION`

Answer (score 1):

How about calling to the shell?  So in Linux:

```
$path = '/path/to/dir/';
$shell_command = escapeshellcmd('find ' . $path .' ! -name "*.zip" -exec rm -r {}');
$output = shell_exec($shell_command);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Mike, I understand shell is king, but I am trying to find a PHP only solution. This project is served by xampp on windows, ouch.

Answer (score 1):

> I would simply like to know the simplest/most efficient way to delete all files in a single directory that are not a .zip file.

[SPL Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) are very effective and efficient.

This is what I would use:

```
$folder = __DIR__;
$it = new FilesystemIterator($folder, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

foreach ($it as $file) {
    if ($file->getExtension() !== 'zip') {
        unlink($file->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw something about this when searching but I've not used them before. I will need to make a note of this and give it a test, many thanks for the advice

Comment: You are welcome. SPL library is not well documented on PHP manual so try other sources as well. This is a good one http://www.sitepoint.com/using-spl-iterators-1/ Good luck! :)

Comment: And if you find SPL library useful as I did then check this book which is the best documentation of SPL I found so far.  http://www.phparch.com/books/mastering-the-spl-library/

Comment: Excellent, I will make a note and have a play around. Many thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$path = "dir/";
$dir = dir($path);
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, -4) !== '.zip') {
    unlink($file);
    }
}
```